# How to fix server response time error showing in Google Pageinsights?

Tags: php, apache, unix, centos, server

I have hosted my magento website on a `VPS` having 3GB RAM & 2CPU core. Even having free memory of approximately 1.9GB I am still facing server response time problems. I am using Apache web server.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Please provide me your website URL to help you better. What is your website?

Comment: it may be due to latency problem? or you have missed some fine tune in server config... many more things to be consider...

Comment: What is your code? What is your error? Please provide more context. you might take a look [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you improve your question.

Comment: @MMPP  Website URL is www.pokyshop.com & Its magento based eCommerce website.

Comment: @user1844933 I don't think so its latency problem. Earlier my website was getting 82 out of 100 in google pageinsights.

Comment: @Kryptos Actually my server is taking too much time to respond. Response time is around 4.4Sec . For the ecommerce websites it should be under 200ms. I tried hard to optimize my server to get rid off this. Like I installed Xcache & installed a module mod_pagespeed by google. Enabled Gzip compression & Set expiry headers too. I increased my numbers in google pageinsights by doing all these but not able to get rid of the server response time. Please help me as its very critical issue for me.

Comment: @AvanishMishra I think you should change your hosting provider.

Comment: @AvanishMishra I agree with 'MM PP''s comment to change hosting provider because your taking too long time to get response. Lot of other factors also impact performance, for good analysis use pingdom tool http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cevBNN/https://www.pokyshop.com/

Comment: As I can see your site's functional area is India so get server which is nearest to India, you can choose AWS and Singapore data center or DigitalOcean and Singapore data center.